# Custom loader in SweetAlert2

Tags: sweetalert2

I want to display a custom loader while the popup is being loaded but no matter what I do, all I get is the default blue sweetalert spinner. As far as I can see, the code below is how it is supposed to be done, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Swal.fire({
  loaderHtml: `<div class="my-spinner"></div>`,
  customClass: {
    loader: 'custom-loader'
  }
})

.custom-loader {
  ...
}

.my-spinner {
  ...
}
```

Comment: most probably you're using outdated version, here's the working example with custom loader: https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/bootstrap.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware of the example that you are referring to, that is where I got the code from above. However, that example does not display a loader when the popup is being loaded, only when you click the OK button. My question was how you set the loader for when the popup window is loading its content. I would assume both loaders would be set the same way but they are not. Do you have an example where the loader at popup generation is customized? We are using the latest version of sweetalert2.